# Necessity of base calls on Overriden Form Event Methods

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

When overriding the Event Methods of a Form, I've so far seen no difference between calling the base method and not calling it.

**Q** - What do the overridden methods really do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for these methods makes no bones about it.  They have a "Note to implementers" phrase that *demands* that you call the base method.  Most of the base method implementations are pretty clean and do nothing but raise the event associated with the method.  So if you override OnPaint, do all of the painting and not call base.OnPaint() then the Paint event won't be raised.  Which works well enough but can be an unpleasant surprise to another programmer that wants to use the Paint event and has no clue why his code doesn't work.

Not all of these base methods are that simple though, they do sometimes do extra stuff.  Like OnFormClosing() calls ValidateChildren().  That might matter, or you might not care by accident.  The complexity of the control is a factor.  A good example is DataGridView, quite unlikely it will work well when you skip the base calls.  This kind of mis-behavior is very hard to diagnose.

There's little point in risking this, you don't have the time machine to tell you that it won't cause trouble.

There's is only one aspect about this that should concern you, not otherwise asked in the question.  Should you call the base method first, then write the customization.  Or should you customize first, then call the base method?  This is the reason these methods exist.  And it is up to you to decide who's the boss.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the specific answers, I would also like to point out that it is generally a good idea to always call the base method that you have overridden even if you know (perhaps through decompiling) that the method does nothing. The reason: the API provider may add code to that method in the future that is critical for the class to function properly. This may be done through a bug fix or a new release. You have no way to know if the provider will be making those changes and when/if they do and your code does not call the base method you will have strange problems where one time your code was working fine.

My rule is to always call the base method unless I have a very clear reason why I must completely override the entire functionality of that base method.

Answer (score 0):

The base methods raise the events themselves.

If you don't call them, any normal handlers will never run.

Comment: What exactly do you refer to as 'normal handlers'?

Comment: Anything that handles the event as an event instead of an override - for example other code in the application that you added via visual studio, which creates event handlers to react to form events instead of overrides.

Comment: But there is no default and / or unseen behavior that will be broken or disturbed by NOT calling the base methods?

Comment: @Acidic indeed, see my more general answer - you don't know if that may change in a future release. You should consider a 3rd party API as completely opaque (as if you do not know what is going on inside). Only look at what the published contract states.